# Getting error while executing arc command to start appium console

Tags: ruby, appium

I am getting following error while executing arc command in terminal to start Appium console.

```
/Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_lib-8.0.0/lib/appium_lib/driver.rb:85:in `load_appium_txt': toml doesn't exist /Users/neetesh/appium/appium.txt (RuntimeError)
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_console-1.0.4/lib/appium_console.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_console-1.0.4/lib/appium_console.rb:37:in `<module:Console>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_console-1.0.4/lib/appium_console.rb:31:in `<module:Appium>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_console-1.0.4/lib/appium_console.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/appium_console-1.0.4/bin/arc:66:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/arc:23:in `load'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/arc:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/neetesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appium ruby console requires an `appium.txt` file to start a session, failing which it throws error.

[Check this file for reference.](https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/android_tests/appium.txt) As per your error logs, file path should be: `/Users/neetesh/appium/appium.txt`